# IAR postbuild batch file call

Tags: batch-file, cmd, iar

I have a question with using IAR embedded workbench IDE ARM 7.60.2

I have a batch file that I run and it generates 2 files. When I click on this sample.bat, it works fine, thus I try to implement it in the postbuild option inside IAR: options **->** build actions and type this:

```
cmd /c "directory....\sample.bat"
```

What ends up happening is that it runs however the files generated are incomplete and have wrong naming scheme.

A weird 'fix' to this issue was for me to copy the `"cmd /c "directory....\sample.bat"` line into a txt file and name it temp.bat, and now insert this into the postbuild command: `cmd /c "directory....\temp.bat"`

This seemed to generate the correct file names when called and worked the same way as manually running sample.bat

I have no clue why this works as I'm not sure if the issue is with IAR or with my *.bat* file itself.

Any input is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that if the batch file is called `sample.bat` it fails, but if it is called `temp.bat` it works? This is hard to belive... **`:(`** I suggest you to add more details in the question.

Comment: I am with @Aacini on this one, the name should not make a difference, unless it was named the same as a system command. Please post more detail, including your script content.

Comment: *"the files generated are incomplete and have wrong naming scheme."* How are the files incomplete? How is the naming scheme wrong? Please read on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got IAR to run the post build step successfully for me

In IDE I enter:
$PROJ_DIR$\src\postbuild.bat $PROJ_DIR$

Then in the bat file I write:
%1\src\myExe.exe /i %1\fw.hex

This will run the batfile postbuild located in the subfolder src of my project file.

This bat file will then start myExe which also is located in same folder and then supply parameter /i and projectfolder follwed by \fw.hex

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, particularly after getting a clean (freshly cloned) copy of the files with Git.  My only solution is to do the unexplained fix from the original question:

- rename the existing batch file
- create a new batch file with the original name
- open both files in a text editor, copy the text from the original file to the new one
- save the new .bat file; close both files
- delete the old/renamed batch file

It could be a line ending issue, and (re-)saving the file with Windows line endings solves the problem.  I noticed the file from the repository had "0x0a" line endings and my new copy has "0x0d 0x0a" endings.